# My AES encrypt datas very shortly and doesn't decrypt them

Tags: c++, encryption, openssl, aes

I am using AES 128 bit in cbc mode. I want to encrypt the datas and put them into the database, and then read them and decrypt. But while doing encryption due to key and vector I used, sometimes it produces an error and sometimes it doesn't. Also when it does the encryption, it encrypts some data very shortly. For example, let's assume data as "packicon_100006.png". It encrypts it as "68b275" but when I tried to decrypt this encrypted string, the app crashes. I can't find out why this happens. I am using OpenSSL with C++.

Error that I told about: `A/libc: invalid address or address of corrupt block 0x9bf33a5c passed to dlfree`

It's not writing anything else to logcat.

My encrypt and decrypt functions:

```
std::string ofxLibcrypto::encrypt(std::string plaintext) {
    unsigned char empty[] = {0};
    unsigned char *ciphertext = empty;
    int lenciphertext = encrypt((unsigned char *) plaintext.c_str(), (int) plaintext.length(), k, v,
                                ciphertext);
    std::string str(reinterpret_cast<char *>(ciphertext));
    clean();
    ofLogVerbose("ofxLibcrypto.cpp") << "encrypted";
    return ofToHex(str.substr(0, lenciphertext));
}

std::string ofxLibcrypto::decrypt(std::string ciphertext) {
    unsigned char empty[] = { 0 };
    unsigned char *plaintext = empty;
    ciphertext = ofHexToString(ciphertext);
    int lenplaintext = decrypt((unsigned char *)ciphertext.c_str(), (int)ciphertext.length(), k, v, plaintext);
    std::string str(reinterpret_cast<char*>(plaintext));
    clean();
    ofLogVerbose("ofxLibcrypto.cpp") << "decrypted";

    return str.substr(0, lenplaintext);
}
```

OpenSSL's encrypt and decrypt functions:

```
int ofxLibcrypto::encrypt(unsigned char *plaintext, int plaintext_len, unsigned char *key, unsigned char *iv, unsigned char *ciphertext) {
  EVP_CIPHER_CTX *ctx;
  int len;
  int ciphertext_len;

  /* Create and initialise the context */
  if(!(ctx = EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new())) handleErrors();

  /* Initialise the encryption operation. IMPORTANT - ensure you use a key
   * and IV size appropriate for your cipher
   * In this example we are using 256 bit AES (i.e. a 256 bit key). The
   * IV size for *most* modes is the same as the block size. For AES this
   * is 128 bits */
  if(1 != EVP_EncryptInit_ex(ctx, EVP_aes_128_cbc(), NULL, key, iv)) handleErrors();

  /* Provide the message to be encrypted, and obtain the encrypted output.
   * EVP_EncryptUpdate can be called multiple times if necessary
   */
  if(1 != EVP_EncryptUpdate(ctx, ciphertext, &len, plaintext, plaintext_len)) handleErrors();
  ciphertext_len = len;

  /* Finalise the encryption. Further ciphertext bytes may be written at
   * this stage.
   */
  if(1 != EVP_EncryptFinal_ex(ctx, ciphertext + len, &len)) handleErrors();
  ciphertext_len += len;

  /* Clean up */
  EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free(ctx);

  return ciphertext_len;
}


int ofxLibcrypto::decrypt(unsigned char *ciphertext, int ciphertext_len, unsigned char *key, unsigned char *iv, unsigned char *plaintext) {
  EVP_CIPHER_CTX *ctx;
  int len;
  int plaintext_len;

  /* Create and initialise the context */
  if(!(ctx = EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new())) handleErrors();

  /* Initialise the decryption operation. IMPORTANT - ensure you use a key
   * and IV size appropriate for your cipher
   * In this example we are using 256 bit AES (i.e. a 256 bit key). The
   * IV size for *most* modes is the same as the block size. For AES this
   * is 128 bits */
  if(1 != EVP_DecryptInit_ex(ctx, EVP_aes_128_cbc(), NULL, key, iv)) handleErrors();

  /* Provide the message to be decrypted, and obtain the plaintext output.
   * EVP_DecryptUpdate can be called multiple times if necessary
   */
  if(1 != EVP_DecryptUpdate(ctx, plaintext, &len, ciphertext, ciphertext_len)) handleErrors();
  plaintext_len = len;

  /* Finalise the decryption. Further plaintext bytes may be written at
   * this stage.
   */
  if(1 != EVP_DecryptFinal_ex(ctx, plaintext + len, &len)) handleErrors();
  plaintext_len += len;

  /* Clean up */
  EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free(ctx);

  return plaintext_len;
}
```

Thanks in advance to everyone.

Comment: How big do you expect your encrypted content to be, and are you absolutely certain it will completely fit inside the `ciphertext` buffer, which is initialized to point to `empty`, an array of a grand total of 1 byte in size? Arrays don't work this way in C++. You must make sure that your output array is big enough in size. Finally, the encrypted array will contain binary garbage, including `\0` bytes. Attempting to construct a `std::string` from a plain `char *` pointer to that will only end in a complete failure.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I'm new to this but it encrypts another shorter datas much longer so I thought it should be longer. When I finished the writing functions, I tried for different sized plaintexts and it had not produced an error. Since I am new to C++ and encryption, I might had made mistakes. Can you give me some hints to correct my mistakes?

Comment: Your program makes an array of 1 byte long. Then it stores the plaintext in that array. Does it fit?

Comment: @user253751 Yes. I tried for some different sized texts and it worked unless the text is so long.

Comment: @SezginOtlak I guess if the text is too long then your code overwrites something important in memory, instead of just overwriting unimportant things.

Comment: @user253751 I will look for it. Thanks.